# O que são os rvalues, lvalues, xvalues, glvalues e prvalues?

Tags: c++, c++11, árvores-de-expressão

Anterior ao C++11 existiam apenas duas categorias de valor para tipos de árvores de expressão: **lvalue** e **rvalue**. De forma bastante simplificada, a primeira representa uma referência que pode ser alterada e cujo endereço pode ser lido, enquanto que a segunda é um temporário, como os valores literais.

Já no C++ houve uma explosão que acrescentou 3 novos tipos. Agora são eles:

**rvalue**
**lvalue**
**xvalue**
**glvalue**
**prvalue**

O standard (no N3337, sessão 3.10 paragrafo 1) diz o seguinte:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
>
> - An **lvalue** (so called, historically, because lvalues could appear on the left-hand side of an assignment expression) designates a function or an object. *[ Example: If `E` is an expression of pointer type, then `*E` is an lvalue expression referring to the object or function to which `E` points. As another example, the result of calling a function whose return type is an lvalue reference is an lvalue. — end example ]*
> - An **xvalue** (an “eXpiring” value) also refers to an object, usually near the end of its lifetime (so that its resources may be moved, for example). An xvalue is the result of certain kinds of expressions involving rvalue references (8.3.2). *[ Example: The result of calling a function whose return type is an rvalue reference is an xvalue. — end example ]*
> - A **glvalue** (“generalized” lvalue) is an lvalue or an xvalue.
> - An **rvalue** (so called, historically, because rvalues could appear on the right-hand side of an assignment expression) is an xvalue, a temporary object (12.2) or subobject thereof, or a value that is not associated with an object.
> - A **prvalue** (“pure” rvalue) is an rvalue that is not an xvalue. *[ Example: The result of calling a function whose return type is not a reference is a prvalue. The value of a literal such as 12, 7.3e5, or true is also a prvalue. — end example ]*

Essa explicação, embora obviamente correta, não é muito clara em explicitar qual o papel de cada categoria em cada contexto, nem ajuda a explicar como classificar o resultado de uma expressão em uma das categorias. Por exemplo, a que categoria `(1+1)`, que se classifica em uma expressão constante integral, pertence?

Como explicar claramente o que é cada categoria?
Qual o objetivo em criar essas novas categorias?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Após alguma muita leitura cheguei nas seguintes conclusões:

---

## `lvalue` (*locator value*):

Denota um valor endereçável.

> Um valor cujo endereço pode ser obtido diretamente (através do operador `&`).

```
int a = 3;
int& b = a;

a   // é lvalue
b   // é lvalue
&a  // não é lvalue (o ponteiro retornado é um temporário, não pode fazer &&a)
3   // não é lvalue (3 é também um temporário)
2+1 // não é lvalue (idem)

const int& c = 2+1;   // Uma referência constante conectada um temporário estende
                      // sua vida pela vida da referencia. "Dar um nome ao temporário".

c;   // é lvalue

struct S {
    int data = 42;
    S* self() { return this; }
    S& operator=(int a) { data = a; return *this; }
};

(S())              // não é um lvalue (embora esteja na memória e tenha endereço this)
(*S().self())      // é um lvalue (exatamente igual ao anterior, mas dessa vez é um lvalue)
(S() = 5)          // não é um lvalue (note que assignment é só uma chamada ao 'operator=')
(S().data)         // não é um lvalue
(S().self()->data) // é um lvalue
```

---

## `xvalue` (*expiring value*):

Denota um valor cuja vida deve terminar no fim da expressão. É um indicativo que os dados podem ser movidos (interfere na resolução de funções sobrecarregadas).

> O valor de retorno de uma função se esta retornar uma referência `&&` para um objeto ou a conversão de um objeto para uma referência `&&`.

```
int&& func() { return 3; }

func()        // é um xvalue
((int&&)3)    // é um xvalue

S s;

std::move(s)  // é um xvalue (std::move não move! É só um cast)
((S&&)s).data // é um xvalue

int&& d = 3;  // vida do temporário é estendida

d   // é um lvalue (qualquer coisa que tenha um nome é um lvalue, 'd' é um nome)
```

---

## `prvalue` (*pure rvalue*):

Denota um temporário que não seja um `xvalue`.

> Um valor que não seja um `lvalue` nem um `xvalue`.

```
// qualquer expressão constante é um prvalue

3           // é um prvalue
1+2         // é um prvalue
sizeof(int) // é um prvalue
nullptr     // é um prvalue
!true       // é um prvalue
[](int a){ return a+1; }  // é um prvalue

// uma função retornando um objeto que não seja referência
// uma conversão para um tipo que não seja referência

int func2 { return 3; }

func2()        // é um prvalue
float(3);      // é um prvalue
float(func2()) // é um prvalue
```

---

## `rvalue`:

Denota valores para os quais criar um ponteiro não faz sentido. O fim da vida do objeto é eminente ou é um temporário.

> Um valor que não seja um `lvalue` (ou seja, é um `xvalue` ou um `prvalue`)

---

## `glvalue` (*generalized lvalue*):

Denota tudo que não é um temporário. Isto é, tudo para o qual pode ser construído uma referência (dessa maneira: `type& var = glvalue`).

> Um valor que não seja um `prvalue` (ou seja, é um `xvalue` ou um `lvalue`)

---

Vale notar que mesmo com a criação dos novos tipos, um valor sempre é um `lvalue` OU um `rvalue`. As duas últimas classificações provavelmente existem para fazer generalizações dentro de outras regras do standard.

Comment: Basicamente sua resposta é complementar à minha, com mais exemplos. Está correta também. Deixo a aceitação da resposta a seu critério.

Answer (score 7):

Vamos do princípio definir cada um pra que fique mais claro:

O compilador do C++ divide o código em expressões para avaliar a sintaxe e a semântica de tudo o que foi usado. Essas expressões fazem parte do corpo da pergunta e são avaliadas em esquema de árvore.

Um `lvalue` (*locator value*) representa um objeto que ocupa uma localização identificável em memória (uma função, por exemplo).

Um `rvalue` é exatamente o contrário: ele **não** representa um objeto em memória. Ele pode ser uma expressão. Por exemplo:

```
int var = 4;
var = (var + 1);
```

`int var` pode ser considerado um `lvalue`.
`(var + 1)` não pode, porque é uma operação, e não um objeto em memória.

Agora fica mais fácil de explicar os outros.

`xvalue` é um objeto expirável. Ele pode ser, por exemplo, uma função anônima que faz cast de um objeto pra outro.

`glvalue` é um objeto que o compilador não decidiu naquele momento se é um `lvalue` ou se é um `xvalue`, e que possivelmente vai ser convertido na etapa de ligação da compilação (função-pra-ponteiro, por exemplo).

`prvalue` é um valor `rvalue` mais puro. Ele **nunca** pode ser um `xvalue`. Substitui completamente o `rvalue` a partir do `C++11`. Pode ser:

- Um Literal, como `42` ou `true` or `nullptr`;
- Uma chamada de função se o tipo do retorno da função ou do operador não é uma referência a um objeto. Por exemplo, `str.substr(1, 2)` ou `2+2`;
- Um cast para outro tipo que não um tipo de referência (ponteiro de função, por exemplo);
- Expressões Lambda, por exemplo `[](int x){return x*x;}` (a partir do C++11).

Comment: Adicionei uma resposta com as conclusões que pude chegar (parece tudo certo?). Uma coisa que não entendi é como é possível que o valor seja definido durante o linktime e não na compilação, já que eles são essenciais para definir a semântica da linguagem?

Comment: Isso não é norma. A etapa de ligação serve justamente para terminar de definir o que a compilação não consegue. Não fui a fundo no mecanismo da avaliação semântica do C++, mas não creio que toda definição seja feita na compilação.

Comment: "`glvalue` é um objeto que o compilador não decidiu naquele momento se é um `lvalue` ou se é um `xvalue`". Você pode mostrar um exemplo em que isso aconteça? Não consigo enxergar um caso que não possa ser definido só com a compilação.

Comment: Por exemplo, uma função que retorna uma referência para uma expressão (um ponteiro de string, por exemplo). Um ponteiro de string não é bem um `rvalue` (porque de fato ele é um objeto), mas se ele pode sofrer um cast implícito (`xvalue`). Li este link aqui: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast, e acho que o compilador consegue predizer a semântica na compilação.