# Como funciona o std::move?

Tags: c++, c++11

Gostaria de entender o funcionamento do `std::move`.

Percebi que com a especificação C++11 surge esta nova função, bem como agora possuímos um novo operador (&&).

Qual a semântica e utilização desta nova função e deste novo operador?

Li algumas explicações em inglês mas não consegui entender por completo o seu funcionamento.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C++ possui duas entidades básicas: valores e tipos. Não é difícil ver que `3` é um valor, que `std::string` é um tipo, que `decltype(itoa(sizeof(4)))` é um tipo e que `double()` é um valor. Os valores em particular carregam três características: a primeira é o estado, as informações que esse valor tem em memória. A segunda é o tipo, todo valor possui um tipo bem definido. A terceira, por fim, é a categoria de valor, que explicarei melhor logo.

Importante notar que apenas a primeira é uma característica de run-time. As duas existem meramente durante a compilação e são descartadas completamente depois de o código ter sido completamente gerado. O tipo do valor gerencia como ele vai se comportar em run-time. Já a categoria do valor especifica como ele deve se comportar em relação ao seu ciclo de vida. Em outras palavras, como saber quando um valor não é mais útil e pode ser seguramente destruído.

As categorias de valor são 5: [rvalues, lvalues, xvalues, glvalues e prvalues](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6373/o-que-s%C3%A3o-os-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-e-prvalues).

Mas o relevante aqui é o `xvalue`. Um valor está nessa categoria quando ele não é mais útil e está eXpirando. Por exemplo:

```
void func(std::string str) { /* ... */ }

func(a);
```

A função `func` precisa ter uma `std::string`. Repare que o argumento é passado por valor, logo ter uma referência não basta, é preciso ter uma `std::string` mesmo. Assim, se `a` **não** for um `xvalue` então `a` ainda é útil e precisa continuar existindo. Sendo assim a única solução é criar uma cópia de `a`. Mas... se `a` for um `xvalue`, então eu sei que `a` está prestes a ser destruído pois não é mais útil. Assim é possível **mover** os dados de `a` para `str` e deixar `a` vazio, afinal `a` será destruído em breve.

O que acontece é que em qualquer contexto que ocorra uma cópia implícita, se o objeto for `xvalue`, então será movido e não copiado. Pois bem, agora vem o lema para nunca ser esquecido:

## `std::move` não move

Isso mesmo, `std::move` não realiza a operação de mover. Em realidade, `std::move` não realiza operação nenhuma e gera zero código. `std::move` é um cast. Pega um valor qualquer como argumento e retorna esse mesmo valor na categoria `xvalue`. E um valor do tipo `T` e na categoria `xvalue` é denotado assim: `T&&`.

A operação de mover em si é executada por um dos construtores do objeto para o qual se move. Esse construtor pega como argumento um `xvalue`, assim: `Objeto(Objeto&& obj)`.  Um exemplo:

```
Objeto b = std::move(a);
```

Aqui fica claro que tudo que `std::move` faz é tornar `a` um `xvalue` para que o construtor correto seja chamado. Mas deve ser notado que `a` ainda não foi destruído, portanto o construtor não pode deixar `a` em um estado inválido. Significando que nada impede que `a` seja usado em sequência.

Duas boas referências que recomendo:
A palestra ["An Effective C++11/14 Sampler" de Scott Meyers](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/An-Effective-Cpp11-14-Sampler)
E o livro do mesmo autor: ["Effective Modern C++"](http://www.aristeia.com/books.html)

Answer (score 3):

Existem várias situações que ou você fica fazendo manipulações específicas para evitar cópia de dados ou permite que estas cópias sejam feitas criando um custo de desempenho.

Isto normalmente ocorre em tipos em que se deseja a semântica de tipo de valor (veja mais sobre o assunto [nessa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/14492/101) e [nessa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16183/101) resposta, é outra linguagem mas a ideia é a mesma) que normalmente são armazenados no [*stack*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15698/101) ou como parte integrante de um outro objeto no *heap*. Ou seja você trabalha efetivamente com o valor do dado e não com uma referência para o efetivo valor. Mas para evitar o custo de cópia desses valores alguns tipos são acessados por referência - através de um ponteiro - mantendo sua semântica de valor. *String* é um caso bem típico.

É verdade que alguns tipo podem ser otimizados pelo compilador e isto acontecia com *string*, por exemplo. Mas o compilador não sabe de todos os tipos. Era precisa permitir que cada tipo fosse definido de tal forma que a otimização sempre fosse feita.

Com o `std::move` é possível mover um valor para outra referência. Isto é feito através de um ponteiro, é muito barato.

Alguém pode estar se perguntando, por que precisa mover? Por que não copia como sempre foi feito no C++? O problema da cópia é que ela retém propriedade do objeto (do valor).

Quando você tem semântica de valor, você nunca tem duas ou mais referências para um objeto (um valor) porque ele é auto referenciado, o valor existe por si só. Quando você copia o valor, a cópia é outro objeto e tem outro proprietário (uma variável, por exemplo). Apesar de inicialmente os valores serem iguais, eles passam ser dois objetos completamente diferentes e independentes.

Você quer garantir que estes tipos que possuem referência mas usam semântica de valor também não tenham mais de um proprietário. Uma simples cópia, criaria uma nova referência para o objeto. Isto tem implicações em ambientes de execução concorrente e complicaria o gerenciamento automático da memória porque teria que controlar quantas referências o objeto tem e só quando tenha zero é que o objeto deva ser destruído.

Como a possibilidade de mover, estamos indicando ao compilador que o objeto só pode ter um proprietário, que não tem como dois proprietários tentarem acessar o objeto simultaneamente e não precisa [controlar quantos proprietário tem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting). Isto simplifica muito tudo o que tem que ser feito no seu código e o que o compilador tem que gerar para controlar o tempo de vida do objeto.

Sempre deu para fazer isto, mas agora tem uma forma padronizada e que o compilador pode se beneficiar já que é padrão. Ele pode tomar decisões baseadas nisto.

Na prática este `std:move` desaparece do código depois de compilado. Ele serve mesmo para informar como o compilador deve lidar com aquilo.

Isto possibilitou criar o `std:unique_ptr` que simplificou muito o gerenciamento automático da memória sem implicar em *overhead* de processamento ou memória. E isto é uma revolução para o C++.

A implementação dele é bem simples, é mais ou menos assim:

```
template <class T>
typename remove_reference<T>::type&&
move(T&& a) {
    return a;
}
```

Exemplo de uso:

```
template <class T> swap(T& a, T& b) {
    T tmp(a); //a passa ter duas referências p/ "a", a original que passou o parâmetro e aqui
    a = b;//e agora duas cópias para "b"
    b = tmp; //mais um cópia para "tmp" que já é cópia para "a"
}
```

Veja a diferença:

```
template <class T> swap(T& a, T& b) {
    T tmp(std::move(a)); //nenhuma cópia é feita em nenhum do casos, só ponteiros se movimentam
    a = std::move(b);   
    b = std::move(tmp);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Syntax/Move.cpp).

Quando você usa o `std:move` a variável está abrindo mão da propriedade do objeto. Que pode ser dada de volta pelo novo proprietário.

Certamente tem muito mais para falar sobre o assunto. E tudo o que eu disse é uma simplificação.

[Referência na Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Rvalue_references_and_move_constructors).

[Documentação pré-oficial](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2027.html#Move_Semantics).

Comment: Acho que estou começando a entender. Mas oque aconteceria se eu fizesse algo como: b = std::move(a); a->foo();
Isto causaria um erro fatal?

Comment: Não. Justamente é por isto que tem o `move`. O compilador sabe o que fazer nesses casos. Toda esta semântica é apenas para deixar o compilador ciente do que ele pode ou não fazer. Neste caso `a` e `tmp` são a mesma coisa. Ambos funcionam. Essencialmente o `move` não muda a forma de fazer nada, muda a forma interna como o compilador lida com isto. Isto é só informação extra para o compilador tratar melhor os seus dados. Talvez vendo seja mais fácil de entender. Veja o que eu fiz: http://ideone.com/L3t9Hb